# ReactJS Routing -> ProtectedRoute - best practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, jwt

I have written a ProtectedRoute which stores after the login in my ReactContext that the User is logged in. But since I store that information locally, isn't that a bad practice?

Should I better send a request to my backend with my actual token, and then route the User to its destination *if* the token is valid?

Or is it valid to store any boolean locally in the Context or ReduxStore?

If it is valid, why? Isn't it a danger since it can be manipulated?

Comment: It depends on whether the user can actually access anything that should be protected. Just being able to visit the page doesn't matter if the API request for the secret data that would be shown on it fails, for example.

Comment: Lets put it that way, i have 3 Pages -> Welcome, Login, Logout where the User doesnt need to be authenticated to access, but then lets say there are few pages where the user have to be authenticated, what then?

Comment: Well is there anything _in the client-side code_ they shouldn't be able to see? React can't protect you from that anyway, as they download the whole codebase to be able to run the app. Everything that _actually_ needs protection should only be exposed via the API, for which they need to be correctly authenticated, so then fiddling with the Redux store won't help them.

Comment: Good Point, and no, there is nothing on the Client-Side which they should not see, all information comes from the backend,

either way, i want the User only to access certain pages when he is logged in, my problem here is, how to go about it, store anything which says "user is logged in" or send an api request which returns the user state

Answer (score -1):

we have different options to store the token on the client-side, we can manually set the token using local storage functions and another option is [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) and as per my opinion redux-persist best option to store the authentication token if you are using the redux in your project.
and the second thing you have mentioned is security, token security we can manage on backend side suppose if someone stole your token and change the token after changing the token user send the request to the server, the server will be sent back unauthorised message,

Comment: No, you dont want to store the Token in your JS, thats why i use httpOnly token,
thats why my question is, if i should save any other value in Redux or Context which serves me as "user is authetnicated" or send a request to the backend on ea. ProtectedRoute view

Comment: yes, we have another option where we can generate the new token for the next API calls, please check this link
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/02/14/modern-token-authentication-in-node-with-express

Comment: we have different options to secure the API's but every options depend on your requirement and project